# What does "it" indicate in these sentences?

Tags: grammar

> 1. **It** drives me crazy whenever you tell me about that
> 2. **It** will be okay if he comes to me.

**"it"** seems like indicating **"whenever you tell me about that"** and **"If he comes to me"** in each sentence.

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of “it does not do (to do something)”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/176882/meaning-of-it-does-not-do-to-do-something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those sentences, "it" does not refer to anything. It is the rule in the English language that all sentences must have a subject, and since there is no actual subject in your examples, "it" is the choice.

It is the same situation as in:

> **It** rains.